# Joining 3 Tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code combining 2 Tables and I would like to add a third one from say vBoAdd C. Where would I need to add the other INNER JOIN line of code?

```
Select A.ID, A.SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY, B.Code, B.Description,
    C.Address1 + ' ' + C.Address2 + ' '+ C.Address3 AS Address, C.Phone
     FROM vBoCsGeneralLookupTables B
    INNER JOIN (
             SELECT A.ID, 
             Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY
             FROM 
             (
                 SELECT ID,
                     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY 
                 FROM  JOA_COMPANY_DEMO A
                 WHERE SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY != ''

             ) AS A CROSS APPLY SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
    ) A
    ON A.SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY=B.Code
    WHERE B.TableName = 'SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY'
```

Comment: you may read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins/16598900

Answer (score 0):

The next `INNER JOIN` can go right before your `WHERE` clause, after the `ON` clause of your first `INNER JOIN`.